# Anylogic build does not produce JAR files

Tags: java, jar, anylogic, executable-jar

I need JAR files of an empty simulation environment. I tried to build my project, and expected to have a compiled version of my project. But I cannot find it anywhere in the project path. I do not use the professional edition of Anylogic and cannot export my model as a standalone Java application. Do you have any ideas? Can you provide me with an exported Java JAR file(s) of an empty simulation?

[image]

Comment: I assume the _"[..] export my model as a standalone Java application"_ is exactly that feature... So, I guess you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the jar files, you need to export it to a Java app. Which you can only do with the Professional version.

Maybe contact support@anylogic.com and ask them if they can provide one for you...